# Не работает авторизация symfony

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, doctrine

Ошибка: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRole() on a non-object in /var/www/symfony.first/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/RoleHierarchy.php on line 43`

Если ходить по разным роутам, то везде белый экран

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    App\AppBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: sha512
        encode-as-base64: true
        iterations: 10

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: /.*
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check/
            login_path: /login/
        logout: true
        security: true
        anonymous: true

access_control:
    - { path: /admin/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace App\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $salt;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
 *                joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *                inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $userRoles;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $status;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $email
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
protected $isActive;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $date_added;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->setDateAdded(new \DateTime());
}

/**
 * Clear user privileges
 **/
public function eraseCredentials()
{

}

/**
 * @return array of Role object
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->getUserRoles();
}

/**
 * Compare one user to another user
 * and determine if its same user
 *
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @return boolean True if equals and false otherwise
 */
public function equals(UserInterface $user)
{
    return md5($this->getUsername()) == md5($user->getUsername());
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $password;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Set status
 *
 * @param boolean $status
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get status
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * Set dateAdded
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateAdded
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setDateAdded($dateAdded)
{
    $this->date_added = $dateAdded;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateAdded
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateAdded()
{
    return $this->date_added;
}

/**
 * Get user roles
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getUserRoles()
{
    return $this->userRoles;
}

/**
 * Set isActive
 *
 * @param boolean $isActive
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setIsActive($isActive)
{
    $this->isActive = $isActive;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get isActive
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getIsActive()
{
    return $this->isActive;
}

/**
 * Add userRole
 *
 * @param \App\AppBundle\Entity\Role $userRole
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function addUserRole(Role $userRole)
{
    $this->userRoles[] = $userRole;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove userRole
 *
 * @param \App\AppBundle\Entity\Role $userRole
 */
public function removeUserRole(Role $userRole)
{
    $this->userRoles->removeElement($userRole);
}

}
```

Role.php

```
<?php

namespace App\AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @var integer $id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @var string $name
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
 *
 * @var DateTime $createdAt
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * Геттер для id.
 *
 * @return integer The id.
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Геттер для названия роли.
 *
 * @return string The name.
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Сеттер для названия роли.
 *
 * @param string $value The name.
 */
public function setName($value)
{
    $this->name = $value;
}

/**
 * Геттер для даты создания роли.
 *
 * @return DateTime A DateTime object.
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Конструктор класса
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Реализация метода, требуемого интерфейсом RoleInterface.
 *
 * @return string The role.
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
}
```

routing.yml

```
Security_login:
path:  /login/
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Security:login" }
requirements:
    methods:  GET

Security_check:
    path:  /login_check/

Security_logout:
    path:  /logout/

Admin_home:
    path:  /admin/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Admin:index" }
    requirements:
        methods:  GET
```

контроллер

```
<?php

namespace App\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
    if ($request->attributes->has(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $request->getSession()->get(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $request->getSession()->get(Security::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error' => $error
    ));
    }
}
```

Хочу также добавить, что версия php - 5.5.9, поэтому ответ про сериализацию не подходит. Версия symfony - 3.1.3

Дамп токена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так запустите дебаг и посмотрите, что приходит RoleHierarchy в 43 строке и почему он не может вызвать getRole()

Comment: @Firepro, там я дебажил ошибку, вместо массива объектов возвращает массив строк (что в принципе так и должно работать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось все просто,

нужно заменить метод в entity User

```
/**
 * @return array of Role object
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = [];
    foreach ($this->getUserRoles() as $role) {
        array_push($roles, $role->getName());
    }
    return $roles;
}
```